# What is meant by 'Polynomial in number of bits in the input'?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

So I have a piece of coursework which is asking a questions about complexity theory where I have some problem, PRIMES, which is in the NPTime complexity class.

All good up to that point.

The thing that is throwing me is a question to come up with a polynomial time algorithms for computing (a^p)mod(b). It has to be polynomial in the size of the input (no of bits).

It's the latter sentence that confuses me.

This is where it loses me! Surely, assuming a brute force attempt (all values between 2 and sqrt(n)), would give 2^NoBits which is exponential?!

Now I don't want the answer! This my coursework so I can't ask for that. I just want clarity on what is meant by 'polynomial in the number of input bits'. Explain it like you would to a child ;)

Comment: Usually when dealing with algorithms and algorithmic run time / complexity, you talk about it in the size of the input. If you have n numbers to sort, you measure sorting algorithms time complexity in terms of n as in O(n^2) or O(n * log(n)) etc. Here, all they are saying is that he size of the input is the number of bits in the input number.

Comment: What it says basically is that the brute force attempt is not good enough. You need an algorithm that only tries roughly`(logN)^k` numbers only, where `k` is a positive integer constant. (And `logN` is of course roughly the number of digits in `N`.)

Comment: Means, if n is the input size, the time to finish is, in big O notation, O(n), O(log n), O(n^2),.. never O(2^n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 numbers, `a`, `p`, and `b`.  Each one can be of any size.  1.  10.  123_456_789.  No limits.

When we write them in base 2, each is some number of bits, followed by that string of bits.  So 1, 110, 111010110111100110100010101.  Each one is some number of bits.  1, 2, 27.  The sum of the number of bits is the total size of your input.  30.

Your algorithm should be efficient enough that there is some polynomial `p(x)` where `x` is the sum of the number of bits in the inputs, which is an upper bound on how long your computation will take.

In particular note that you do not want to multiply `a` by itself `p` times!